# TYPOSCRIPT: stdWrap.replacement in text fields only

Tags: text, replace, typo3, field, typoscript

I usually search and replace to german quotation marks via stdWrap.

```
lib content {
    20 < styles.content.get
    20.select.where = colPos = 0
    stdWrap.replacement{
         20 {
            search = #(&quot;)#
            replace = |*| &bdquo;||&ldquo; |*|
            useRegExp = 1
            useOptionSplitReplace = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Never had problems, but now I want to replace CO2 into CO<sub>2</sub>. But: Also files and images has CO2 in their names. And this search and replace also replaces strings in path- and filenames.

Does anyone knows, how to limit the stdWrap-function to text fields only (text, header, caption) or exclude specific fields (image, files)?

Thanks for help :)

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with a lookahead for that:

```
lib.content {
  20 < styles.content.get
  20.select.where = colPos = 0
  stdWrap.replacement{
    20 {
      search = #(?![^<>]*>)(co2)#i
      replace = CO<sub>2</sub>
      useRegExp = 1
    }
  }
}
```

The `(?![^<>]*>)` will make sure any text between < and > will not be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

A replacing only for texts (coming from e.g. `bodytext`) only will be very complicated and could be done probably only on output of that specific field (in typoscript or FLUID).
But what if the text contains a link to a file which contains a `CO2` in the filename?.
Nearly impossible to catch.

You could try to use regexp to catch only words (limited by whitespace or punctuation marks, not used in filenames).

The better solution would mean more work for editors:
Don't replace just `CO2` but make it unique like `__CO2__` or `##CO2##`.
And although this character sequence also is possible in filenames it's probability is much lower than just `CO2`

Comment: Hallo Bernd, to replace #CO2# was my fallback, but regExp is a good Idea. Thanks  anyway

Comment: or you enable the option to mark text as subscript (and superscript) for the editors. Then the editors are responsible themself for correct indizes.